# python tensorflow import issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
in swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
     19         except ImportError:

c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\imp.py in
find_module(name, path)
    295     else:
--> 296         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    297 

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
last)
c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py
in <module>
     53     # use `dlopen()` for dynamic loading.
---> 54     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     55 except ImportError:

c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
in swig_import_helper()
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             import _pywrap_tensorflow
     21             return _pywrap_tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24204/4081599546.py in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
      2 from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
      3 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
      4 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py
in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py
in <module>
     58 please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
     59 from there.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 60   raise ImportError(msg)
     61 
     62 # Protocol buffers

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])   File
"c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\imp.py",
line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel, you should
not try to import tensorflow from its source directory; please exit
the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from
there.`
```

- i've checked MSVCP.dll in my sys32 folder.
- I think my tensorflow is using CPU. (I have Nvidia MX250)

Answer (score 0):

Set your Nvidia CPU to false or make sure you install at the top of the code using ! before the command

Comment: can you show me how? please.

Comment: !pip install --upgrade tensorflow ----- at the top of your note

Comment: does it work for you

Comment: no i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you explain your issue properly, seems I am not clear